# How can i change setting of Pivot column in C#

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

How can i change this setting in C# using `Aspose.Cells` library ? Please Help....

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M00D.png)

This is my Pivot :

```
     Aspose.Cells.Worksheet sheet2 = XLS.Worksheets.Add("pivotcha");
        Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotTableCollection pivotTables = sheet2.PivotTables;
        int index = pivotTables.Add("=Data!A1:" + "" + array_columns[dtb.Columns.Count-1].ToString() + "" + (dtb.Rows.Count+1).ToString() + "", "B3", "pivotcha");
        Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables[index];
        pivotTable.RowGrand = true;
        pivotTable.ColumnGrand = true;

        pivotTable.AutoFormatType = Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotTableAutoFormatType.Report1;
        pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Column, 3);
        pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Column, 4);
        pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Column, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :
PivotTable.RowFields[index].ShowCompact = true;

Comment: Besides, you may try PivotTable.ShowInCompactForm() method if you want to layout the entire PivotTable in compact form. --- Regards, Shakeel Faiz --- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose